# Python tkinter application doesn't respond when run when 0 errors?

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, pytube

I'm new to python and I'm trying to develop a basic application to download a YouTube video through url using the the pytube API. Unfortunately my IDE (pycharm) isn't showing any errors and my program crashes with a 'not responding' message. Would anyone have any ideas? All help is appreciated.

Cheers :)

I've tried removing Pytube functions
Ive also tried restarting Pycharm and the project
I've tried deleting functions and different configurations of my code

The program should just run with the widgets in the correct x+y positions before any widget functionality.`

```
    import os
    import tkinter as tk
    from pytube import YouTube

     root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("YouTube converter")
    root.geometry('800x300')

root.iconbitmap(r'C:\\Users\\matthew.harris\\youtube_tool\\youtube_tool\\icon.ico')
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    root.tk_setPalette(background='light grey')

    save_location = 'C:\\Users\\', os.environ.get('USER'), '\\Desktop'
    link = input()
    yt = YouTube(link)

    mp4files = yt.filter('mp4')
    download_func = yt.get(mp4files[-1].extension, mp4files[-1].resolution)


def get_video():
    try:
        download_func.download(save_location)
    except download_func as error:
        print('Some error')
        print('task completed')


textEntry = tk.Entry(root, font=100, width=50, bg='white', command=get_video())
textEntry.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=0, pady=40)

youtubeID = tk.Label(root, text='Youtube video url')
youtubeID.place(x=1, y=45)

Convert_Button = tk.Button(root, text='Convert', command=get_video()).place(x=700, y=40)

videoOption = tk.IntVar()
R1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='MP3', variable=videoOption, value='MP3').place(x=500, y=100)
R2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Video', variable=videoOption, value='Video').place(x=200, y=100)

root.mainloop()
``
```

Comment: first run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe without IDE - maybe it will show you error message.

Comment: commn mistake - `command=` needs function name without `()` (so called "callback") and when you press button then it will run it using `()`. Currently you have `command=get_video()` so it runs `get_video()` when you start program.

Comment: `Entry` doesn't expect option `command=` so you can't use `Entry(..., command=...)`

Comment: to create path with location you should use `+` instead of `,` - `'C:\\Users\\' +  os.environ.get('USER') + '\\Desktop'` or string formatting with `{}` - `'C:\\Users\\{}\\Desktop''.format(os.environ.get('USER'))` or function specially for pathes - `os.path.join('C:\\Users\\', os.environ.get('USER'), 'Desktop')`. Currently you create tuple with 3 elements instead of one string with location.

Comment: I expect that it will need some time to download file and it may block `mainloop()` to get key/mouse events from system so window will freeze. You may have to run `downoad()` in separated thread and then `mainloop()` will run in main thread.